# Web Scrape - not Working with a link, no result

Tags: php, html, dom

i got a problem. I did that script with php to obtain the price of a web.

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php'); //Library
$url = "https://www.exito.com/products/MP00550000000204/Televisor+LG+Led+43+Pulgadas+Full+HD+Smart+TV+43LJ550T"; //Link
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
$post = $html->find('p[class=price offer]', 0)->plaintext;
$resultado = str_replace ( ".0", '', $post);
echo $resultado;
?>
```

So, if i test with the link that is on the code it works and shows me the price of the article **1186900**

But when i change the link for one of the same page (this)
https://www.exito.com/products/0000225183192526/Carne+Res+Molida+En+Bandeja
I test the script and it does not shows me anything.

I don´t understand because it is the same page and the price is in the same `<p></p>` that all the articles.

**What am i doing wrong?**

*NOTE: Remember that if you want to test the script you need to download the **simple_html_dom.php** [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)*

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: The page with carnes on it has multiple prices, that may cause a problem. I know this will probably falls on deaf ears, but please ask for permission before you scrape a site, it is the polite thing to do. They might even has something like an API or download which is easier for you, and saves them money.

Comment: Thanks, and it is just to learn how scrap i am not going to use this information. But that problem i can not solve, however in the other link (TV) it has multiple prices too.

Comment: I checked again, no the link in your code has only one `<p class="price offer">...</p>`.